# eGit checkout conflict - can't reset

Tags: eclipse, egit

I have 2 branches: master & develop. I have been developing in "develop" and committed everything I need. What was left (application generated file: .out) I didn't care for! So when I went to switch branch, I got prompted  following:

[image]

I clicked "Reset" however instead of switching to the branch I got prompted the same "Checkout Conflicts" windows with exactly the same choices. I clicked "Reset" again, however above process just repeated. I clicked a while -- no help the same happens again and again. More over I encountered the same scenario on different eclipses (Juno, Kepler) and different OS (Mac & Windows).

Am I doing something wrong? I don't want to commit or stash the file, I just want it to be reset. Is it a bug? Or there is a solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Add `*.out` to your `.gitignore` to get rid of those files once and forever.**

---

In my version of egit, when i select reset, the reset window opens. Seems like a bug in your version. Try updating egit (not only eclipse).

If it still doesn't work, you can also use `Team -> Reset...` to perform a reset. After that you should be able to change the branches.

Actually, there are a few more ways to kill a file:

- just delete the file
- commit it and then reset the branch to the commit before that (effectively getting rid of that commit)
- commit it and then perform an `git rebase -interactive` and delete the corresponding line

Feel free to edit this post and add more ways of violently killing a file from git!

Comment: I'll give it a try and will let you know

Comment: I've commited changes, switched to another branch, deleted the previous branch, and pulled it once again from repo

Comment: @Melr let ME know ;)